# Calculate specific Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sensor measures like this.

```
SensId   Max_Timestamp    Min_Timestamp       Value
-------------------------
1        2021-03-19 10:05 2021-03-18 10:03    139,5
2        2021-03-19 10:07 2021-03-18 10:07    73,2
3        2021-03-19 10:01 2021-03-18 09:58    10,3
4        2021-03-19 10:04 2021-03-18 10:02    0
5        2021-03-19 10:01 2021-03-18 10:00    3,2
6        2021-03-19 10:00 2021-03-18 10:03    0
```

Ill try make and SQL view where Ill calculate the Value to different zones.

Zone1 = Sens1 - Sens2 + Sens3 + Sens4 - Sens5 + Sens6

ex. Zone1 value_used = 139,5 - 73,2 + 10,3 + 0 - 3,2 + 0 = 64,4

Zone2 = Sens2 - Sens3 - Sens4 + Sens5 - Sens6

Zone3 = Sens5

The result Ill try to get is this.

```
Zone   Timestamp            Value_used
-------------------------
1      2021-03-19 10:00     64,4
2      2021-03-19 10:00     66,1
3      2021-03-19 10:00     3,2
```

Actually I do not know how to start. My SQL knowledge is not that good and the only result I manage to get is one of the zones, not all of them.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the Zone# calculations? When you mention Sense 1 are you referring to the senseid = 1? How do you calculate the Value_used of the result set?

Comment: Oww actually it aint that easy to explain the logic of the zones. Like Zone1 is calculated as value of sensId 1 (139,5) - value of sensId 2 (73,2) + value of sensID 3 (10,3) + value of SensID 4 (0) - value of sensID 5 (3,2) + value of sensID 6 (0) = 64,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method might be `union all`:

```
select 1 as zone, max(max_timestamp) as max_timestamp,
       sum(case when sensid in (1, 3, 4, 6) then value
                when sensid in (2, 5) then - value
           end) as value_used
from t
union all
select 3 as zone, max(max_timestamp),
       sum(case when sensid in (2, 5) then value
                when sensid in (,3, 4, 6) then - value
           end)
from t
union all
select 1 as zone, max(max_timestamp),
       sum(case when sensid in (5) then value
           end)
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure out how to do. You missed AS value_used in column 3 and max_timestamp gave me records of every timestamp. Ill just wanted one record of time for each zone.

Comment: @Maw . . . I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Yeh, thats how I did it. On MAX(max_timestamp) I choosed to put an case when sensid like MAX(case when sensid in (1,3,4,6,2,5) then max_timestamp end).
Thanks again for the help.